# Let $(X_1,...,X_r) \sim Mult(n,r,p_1,...,p_r)$. Determine whether X1 and X2 are independent.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $(X_1,...,X_r) \sim Mult(n,r,p1,...,p_r)$. Determine whether $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent.

So I'm thinking that I need to have $P(X_1=k)P(X_2=m) = P(X_1=k \cap X_2=m)$, but I'm stuck on where to go from here.

Comment: Learn some latex. http://www.thestudentroom.co.uk/wiki/LaTex. Best resource imo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at whether or not $P(X_1=n)P(X_2=n) =\ P(X_1=n,X_2=n)$.

Comment: I understand that's the definition for independence, but how to I represent these probabilities so I can work out if they're independent or not?  I know that they are, from the definition, but I need to show a proof.

Comment: @user181928: you need to analyze the multinomial distribution more closely. What *must* $X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n$ satisfy?

Comment: Not sure how to type this out, but am I looking for the pmf of the Multinomial?  Also, I think I just realized, am I just using the binomial distribution for the left half of the equation?

Comment: Just read this section here on the mass function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution#Specification